# async.forEach - performing logic for each file, and then executing a function when done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to perform some logic for each of my files.

Here is my current code...

```
        async.forEach(list, function(file, loopCallback)
        {       
                fq.readFile('./directoryOfFiles/' + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) 
                {
                    // Calling a function that performs said logic...
                    functionInAnotherFile(data, function(result, newLastRead)
                    {
                        // Calling the loop callBack after working with each file...
                        loopCallback();
                    });

                });

        },
        function(err)
        {
                console.log("HOW CAN I GET HERE?"); 
        });
```

I am trying to get that "HOW CAN I GET HERE?" string to print, AFTER all of the files are finished being read, but for some reason, I never arrive down there?

Comment: What is the library you use?

Comment: Are you sure, that `loopCallback()` is called for absolutely all files in the list?

Comment: Can you post functionInAnotherFile() also?